# UITextField inside UITablecell, expand cell when textfield expands

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, uitextview

I have been searching the internet for hours but can't seem to find a solution in Xamarin.iOS where the table row height automatically increases when user types in textview.

I have a UITextView (that grows when user types), inside a UITableViewCell.

Any ideas?

Comment: This link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486674/xamarin-ios-how-to-make-a-self-sizing-uitableviewcell-while-editing) may help you.

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT thank you so much! I finally got it to work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.